# Label top alignment

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm trying to put the temperature in my app. I would like to show it like that:
[image]

But all I'm able to get is that:

[image]

I have tried to use this code to align the two label on top:

```
@IBDesignable class TopAlignedLabel: UILabel {
    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        if let stringText = text {
            let stringTextAsNSString = stringText as NSString
            let labelStringSize = stringTextAsNSString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: self.frame.width,height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil).size
        super.drawText(in: CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: self.frame.width, height:ceil(labelStringSize.height)))
        } else {
            super.drawText(in: rect)
        }
    }
}
```

It worked on for the '°C' but it's not working for the 25. Can someone help me find a solution to my problem ?

Comment: you set control in vertical align from story board

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to solve this is with attributed strings:

```
let tempText = "25˚C"
let baseFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 23.0)!
let superscriptFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)!
let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: tempText, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: baseFont])
attrStr.addAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: superscriptFont, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: 10.0], range: NSMakeRange(2,2))

myLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

You can keep adding more different attributes on any range you want by using the `addAttributes` method.

Answer (score 1):

A font has multiple characteristics, including Ascender, Descender, CapHeight, etc... So what your code gets is *not* a way to align the character glyphs flush with the top of the label frame, but rather it aligns the *Font* bounding box to the top of the frame.

Calculating the offset between font metrics *might* give you what you're after. Here is one example (you can run it in a Playground page):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {

    let labelOne: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 60.0)
        label.text = "25"
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        label.textAlignment = .right
        return label
    }()

    let labelTwo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24.0)
        label.text = "°C"
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 1
        return label
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the scroll view to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(labelOne)
        self.view.addSubview(labelTwo)

        // constrain the scroll view to 8-pts on each side
        labelOne.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
        labelOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true

        labelTwo.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.rightAnchor, constant: 2.0).isActive = true


        if let f1 = labelOne.font, let f2 = labelTwo.font {
            let offset = (f1.ascender - f1.capHeight) - (f2.ascender - f2.capHeight)
            labelTwo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelOne.topAnchor, constant: offset).isActive = true
        }

    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
vc.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Depending on what font you are actually using, though, that may not be good enough. If so, you'll want to look into CoreText / `CTFont` / `CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters()` / etc.